# Error while connecting .net 5 app with sql server using docker

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, docker, entity-framework

I've been trying to connect .net 5 app with mssql server using docker. I've been always getting this error: **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'sa'.**

This is appsetting.json file:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
  "OrderingConnectionString": "Server=localhost;Database=OrderDb;User 
  Id=sa;Password=SwN@12345678;"
  },
```

This is docker-compose.yml file:

```
  orderdb:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

This is docker-compose.override.yml file

```
  orderdb:
    container_name: orderdb
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "SwN@12345678"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "1433:1433"
```

Can anyone help me to solve that?

Comment: The database is probably not local.  It is attached to the SQL Server.  Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to database.  The login window has the server name and use this name in the connection string.  Also check if the credentials match the connection string.  If the login window has Windows Credentials than use Integrated Security = true instead of the username and password.

Comment: @jdweng thank you. You solved my problem.